# Cuteeditor not working in IE 11 after Patch

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11, cuteeditor

Our company just installed an IE 11 patch and it broke the CuteEditor that we are using for an internal ASP.NET 3.5 website. We have changed the X-UA-Compatible to IE11 and EDGE with no success. It works fine on our local machines, but does not work on the server. Our enterprise has Enterprise Mode and Compatibility mode setup for Intranet sites. After the patch installed, we no longer have the CuteEditor toolbar and the textboxes are readonly. It works fine in Chrome, but that's not really a viable solution for a large enterprise right now.

[Here is a link to the MS for the patch that was installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3154070)

Can anyone shed any light on what we need to do?

Answer (score 0):

We found a fix for the issue. We had to disable partial rendering in the update panels that the cuteeditor controls were in.